# How to present custom alertview and system permissions alertviews sequentially in order.

Tags: ios, objective-c, permissions, uialertview

I have an app that uses Location Services and Notifications(I have no control over the alert views they present to confirm/deny permission). The first time I start the app, it asks for permission to use both features from alert views. I also have 2 custom permissions that I want to present as alert views. My question is how do I order them sequentially and have the next alert view appear after I confirm/deny the current one. My initial idea is to have an isPermissionSet flag for each permission and the next permission to be presented requires all the previous permissions to be set before it's able to be presented. After each permission is set, I call a refresh method which checks for all permissions(since my app runs asynchronously). Are there better design patterns that tackle this problem?

Comment: The permission alerts only appear the first time your app tries to make use of those feature or ask for permission. So you need logic that ensures your app doesn't request the 2nd feature until the 1st one has been processed.

Answer (score 0):

For the two custom permissions you can use UIAlertController and UIAlertAction to present the alerts sequentially. I am presuming that the result of one permission does not affect the other permission request. So you can do this

```
func askPermissions1() {
  //Create UIAlertAction objects for Yes and No buttons and in their action handlers call askPermission2()
  //Create UIAlertController with the actions created above and present it
}

func askPermissions2() {
  //Create UIAlertAction objects for Yes and No buttons and in their action handlers call askLocation()
  //Create UIAlertController with the actions created above and present it
}

func askLocation() {
  //request for location here and handle the location manager delegate methods to determine what the user has chosen
  //In the delegate methods call askPushNotification()
}

func askPushNotification() {
  //request for push notification permission and handle their delegate accordingly
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The 1st permission determines if the 2nd, 3rd & 4th gets asked. The 3rd & 4th doesn't care if 2nd is confirmed or denied. My app works asynchronously, so each time I confirm/deny a permission, I perform a refresh and check all permission. I want the permission that shows up next to be the correct one and only shows up once. My current solution requires me to check for a bunch of flags to show the correct one. I'm just wondering if there's a better solution/design pattern that solves this issue.